# MS Access: JOIN expression not supported

Tags: ms-access

I have 3 tables: client, contract & client_contract_xref (joining table, for the many to many relationship)

I want to return all the records from the client and contract tables. Some clients may not have a contract, and some contracts may not be assigned to a client yet.

I have tried:

```
SELECT 
  client.clientID, 
  client.name,
  client.email,
  contract.contractID,
  contract.repayments
FROM (client 
LEFT JOIN client_contract_xref ON client.ClientID = 
  client_contract_xref.client_fk)
LEFT JOIN contract ON client_contract_xref.contract_fk = contract.contractID
```

This return all the clientID's but not all the ContractID's. If I replace the 2'nd LEFT JOIN with RIGHT JOIN I get an error: JOIN expression not supported.

I have different number of columns in my two main Tables so can't use a union query.

Comment: Try removing the parentheses.

Comment: Please correct your tags -- MySQL is not the same as MS-ACCESS.

Comment: A UNION can be constructed even if tables have different number of columns but why would you use a UNION? The result would not be the same as with a JOIN. How can a contract not have a client?

Comment: Hi Barmar. removing the parentheses cause syntax  error (missing operator). The backend is MySql - not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: June7: Thanks for the info. Yeah...I did not really think a union would be the solution.  Wrt contract without clientID: Every applicant gets a contractID, but only gets a client ID once the application/contract is approved or when I can confirm the applicant is an existing client, in which case I assign an existing clientID to the contract. The contract table was called application initially, which may make more sense, but was changed for another reason.

Comment: UNION should work fine - use the above code, then UNION, then the above code but replace both `LEFT JOIN` with `RIGHT JOIN`?